# c++ return string based on pair of integers

Tags: c++

I have a list of sites, e.g. site1, site2, site3, etc (a rather long one at that) that are mapped to a pair of single-digit integers that my program receives from it's remote client, and I need an efficient way to return (as a string) the site  name based on this pair of integers. The first digit is significant by itself, and the second digit is not significant unless paired with the first. These "site codes" should each return a unique string.

Here's how I'm doing it currently:

```
#include<string>
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>

// sbits is a vector of integers from which these two integers are being pulled
std::string readSite( vector<int> sbits ) {
    int rgcode = sbits[5];
    int uid = sbits[6];
    if ( rgcode == 0 ) {
        if ( uid == 0 ) {
            return "site1";
        }
        else if ( uid == 1 ) {
            return "site2";
        }
        else if ( uid == 2 ) {
            return "site3";
        }
        // throw an exception if it's  not here
        else {
             std::throw 10;
        }
    }
    else if ( rgcode == 1 ) {
        if ( uid == 0 ) {
            return "site4";
        else if ( uid == 1 ) {
            return "site5";
        else {
            std::throw 10;
        }
    }
    else {
        std::throw 5;
    }
    std::catch( int err ) {
        std::cout << "An exception has occurred. Error "<< err << " closing." << std::endl;
        exit;
    }
}
```

Everything about this makes me die a little inside. It's tiresome to write, tiresome to read, and probably sub-optimal for what I need to do.

So my question is this: Is there a more elegant (and less suicide-inducing) way to do this?
I've been reading about std::enum, std::map, but they don't seem to fit what I'm trying to do here.

edit: Is there a way to do this using an ordered list of some sort for the sites? Something so I don't have to go through and write 70+ variations of the same line. Some way to iterate through each? Maybe?

Comment: Why can't use use std::map?  The key to the map can be a more complex structure.  Or, if your code values lie within a range, scale one and add the other to it to make a unique key.

Comment: Because I couldn't figure out how to implement it properly :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define data structure properly to simply your code:

```
typedef std::pair<int, int> RgCodeUidPair;
//               rgcode, uid
```

Then you can search through cachedData map by using `(rgcode, uid)` as pair.

```
std::string readSite( int rgcode, int uid)
{ 
   static std::map<RgCodeUidPair, std::string> cachedData; // cache data, only load once
   if (cachedData.empty())
   {
     cachedData.insert(make_pair(make_pair(0, 0), "site1"));
     cachedData.insert(make_pair(make_pair(0, 1), "site2"));
     cachedData.insert(make_pair(make_pair(1, 0), "site3"));
     cachedData.insert(make_pair(make_pair(1, 1), "site4"));
   }

   auto it = cachedData.find(make_pair(rgcode, uid));
   if (it != cachedData.end())
   {
      return it->second;
   }
   // throw if not found
}
```

Comment: I've got over 70 sites though, would that scale well in this case?

Comment: Is there a way to do this using an ordered list of some sort for the sites? Something so I don't have to go through and write 70+ variations of the same line. Some way to iterate through each? Maybe?

Comment: @Oblivious12 if you have many sites, you could put them in a txt file and load them in another function.

Comment: I could, but doing that a few thousand times every five minutes would probably slow things down quite a bit. The program this is for is multithreaded on a pretty large scale (1-2k servers making simultaneous connections every five minutes), And that would generate a lot of IO... it's bad enough that it's all going into a database, so I think I'll avoid that for now and just go with your method. Thanks!

Comment: @Oblivious12 load sites to db just need to be run in once, make it static in function. :)

Comment: URGH I've been putting off figuring out the mysql c++ connector... not because the code itself is difficult, but because my build system can't locate the correct library files, meaning that even the code the mysql gives as examples won't compile.

Comment: I've been having a problem with compiling this: I get: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âitâ with no type

Answer (score 1):

Another way of looking at things:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>

std::string const& readSite(std::vector<int> const& sbits ) {

  static std::array<std::array<std::string, 10>, 10> const strs{{
    {{ "site1", "site2", "site3" }},
    {{ "site4", "site5" }}
  }};

  return strs.at(sbits.at(5)).at(sbits.at(6));
}
```

A few points

- Needs error handling for empty strings (can be handled upstream if necessary)
- Note how the vector is passed by reference
- Throw an actual `exception` class instead of an `int`.

Comment: Why would I need to pass sbits by reference? sbits isn't being modified, just read.

Comment: @Oblivious12 If you don't pass by reference you are copying the vector every time you call the function. `const` reference ensures it cannot be changed.

Comment: Well in theory, this should only get called once per thread, although since the program I'm working on will typically have between 1000 and 2,000 threads, I suppose that might make a pretty significant difference.

Comment: @Oblivious12 even if it's only called once in the entire program it's still a free optimization, you should get into the habit of passing non-trivial types as references.

Answer (score 1):

A rather simple way is to reduce the pair of int to a unique string and then use to store the sites.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

typedef map <string, string> SiteMap;
typedef pair<int, int> IntPair;

SiteMap map;

string ConvertPairToStr (IntPair const& pair)
{
    int first  = pair.first;
    int second = pair.second;

    stringstream unq;
    unq << first;
    unq << "_";
    unq << second;

    return unq.str();
}

void StoreSite (string site, IntPair p)
{
    string unq = ConvertPairToStr(p);
    map [p] = site;
}

string GetSite (IntPair p)
{
    string unq = ConvertPairToStr(p);
    // Assuming site is already stored
    return map[p];
}
```